# Battleships ships can't be placed on the edge

Tags: java, android

it's me again. I'm trying to make a very simple Battleships game.
Now I want to make ships be separated with at least one free cell. Look at the picture

[image]

As you see, the edge is completely ship-free, which makes available number of placement much smaller (or less? sorry for my bad English).

The "Field" is simply an int[10][10] array.

I have a very rude method to check avaibality to place ship:
(IS_WATER const = 0)

```
private static boolean checkIfShipAvailable(int x, int y, int dir, int length) {
         int counter = 0;
        switch(dir) {
        case DIRECTION_RIGHT:
            try {
                if(field[x-1][y] == IS_WATER) counter++;     
                if(field[x-1][y-1] == IS_WATER) counter++;    
                if(field[x-1][y+1] == IS_WATER) counter++;    
                if(field[x][y-1] == IS_WATER) counter++;      
                if(field[x][y+1] == IS_WATER) counter++;     
                if(field[x+1][y-1] == IS_WATER) counter++;    
                if(field[x+1][y+1] == IS_WATER) counter++;    

                if(field[x+length-1][y-1] == IS_WATER) counter++;
                if(field[x+length-1][y+1] == IS_WATER) counter++;
                if(field[x+length][y] == IS_WATER) counter++;
                if(field[x+length][y-1] == IS_WATER) counter++;
                if(field[x+length][y+1] == IS_WATER) counter++;

            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                counter++;
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Direction: Right. Counter = " + counter);
            if (counter == 12)
                return true;
            break;

        case DIRECTION_DOWN:
            try {
                if(field[x-1][y-1] == IS_WATER) counter++ ;
                if(field[x][y-1] == IS_WATER) counter++ ;
                if(field[x+1][y-1] == IS_WATER) counter++ ;
                if(field[x-1][y] == IS_WATER) counter++ ;
                if(field[x+1][y] == IS_WATER) counter++ ;
                if(field[x-1][y+1] == IS_WATER) counter++ ;
                if(field[x+1][y+1] == IS_WATER) counter++ ;

                if(field[x-1][y+length-1] == IS_WATER) counter++ ;
                if(field[x+1][y+length-1] == IS_WATER) counter++ ;
                if(field[x-1][y+length] == IS_WATER) counter++ ;
                if(field[x][y+length] == IS_WATER) counter++ ;
                if(field[x+1][y+length] == IS_WATER) counter++ ;

            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                counter++;
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Direction: Down. Counter = " + counter);
            if (counter  == 12)
                return true;
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

That's for 2-4 cell ships. And for 1-cell ship:

```
private static boolean checkIfOneAvailable(int x, int y) {
         int counter = 0;
         try {
                if(field[x-1][y-1] == IS_WATER) counter++ ;
                if(field[x][y-1] == IS_WATER)counter++ ;
                if(field[x+1][y-1] == IS_WATER) counter++ ;
                if(field[x-1][y] == IS_WATER) counter++ ;
                if(field[x+1][y] == IS_WATER) counter++ ;
                if(field[x-1][y+1] == IS_WATER) counter++ ;
                if(field[x+1][y+1] == IS_WATER) counter++ ;
                if(field[x][y+1] == IS_WATER) counter++ ;   
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {     
          counter++;
        } 
         if (counter == 8) 
             return true;
        return false;

     }
```

Could you tell me, where's the mistake and how I can make ships be placed even on edges?

Comment: You don't want to test for water. You want to check if there's not another ship already.

Comment: IS_WATER means empty cell

Comment: I see that. But if you try to do it by testing for ships, the algorithm will be easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Don't test for water. Test if another ship is there. Like this:

```
private static boolean checkIfOneAvailable(int x, int y) {        
    if(x!=0 && y!=0 && field[x-1][y-1] == IS_SHIP) return false;
    if(y!=0 && field[x][y-1] == IS_SHIP) return false;
    ...
    return true;
 }
```

Note that I've added the checks for array bounds to the condition. **Using exception for flow control is considered a bad habit** mainly because it's slow. 
When using this approach, you'll also get the performance gain from the fact, that you don't always have to check all the surrounding fields. Once you find a collision, you get the result.

Also there is no point in copy-pasting the code for larger ships. Until you have placed the ship, you can still do the same check for every field of the larger ships:

```
private static boolean checkIfAvailable(int x, int y, int dir, int length){
    for (int i = 0; i<length; i++){
        switch (dir) {
            case DIRECTION_RIGHT:
                if (!checkIfOneAvailable(x+i,y))
                    return false;
                break;
            case DIRECTION_DOWN:
                if (!checkIfOneAvailable(x,y+i))
                    return false;
                break;
        }             
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it will be applicable for larger ships, as field[x+1][y] while Direction is right will always give false, for example. But it's just a note

Comment: I don't understand. why would it be false? I thought you're placing the whole ship after you check if it can be placed. So If you have a ship 2*1, then you check if both pieces of the ship can be placed. Where's the catch?

Comment: Could you please look at this: http://pastebin.com/LeH6bANt ... no ships are placed on bottom and right side..

Comment: There may also be a problem in other methods. I think that what you've posted is fine. Try it with debugger. It's not hard at all to set it up and you'll find plenty of tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

If an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` occurs all later `if(field...` lines up to the `catch` are never executed and the counter isn't increased anymore.

Better solution: Create a method which takes coordinates and returns either the `field[x][y]` value or a special `OUT_OF_BOUNDS` value (by catching `IndexOutOfBoundsException` or checking the bounds)

Comment: you mean (if ((field[x+1][y] == IS_WATER) || myNewMethod == true) ?

Comment: You beat me to it! In the future he could also run the app in debug mode and step through the method. That would give  a faster response than  asking Stack Overflow, though that would deprive us from fighting for rep points haha.

Comment: @Kondra007 No, replace your `field[x+1][y] == IS_WATER` by `myNewMethod(x+1,y) != IS_SHIP`

Comment: @Mr.Will, by the way, could you give a link to explanation how to use debugger in Eclipse? I'm used to debug in my brain, but it's hard sometimes.